# Find duplicates in table by checking 4 columns

Tags: php, sql, count, duplicates, subquery

Table * articles contains 6 7 columns.

```
id  |  Article    | Date        |  Document   |   In    |   Out   |   Status
1       7156       2020-10-26      test           0          14        1
2       7157       2020-10-27      test 2         0          15        1
3       7158       2020-10-28      test 3         0          14        1 
4       7156       2020-10-26      test           0          14        1
```

Is there a way I can find and list all duplicates for 4 columns  (article, document, in).

Duplicate for the table above would be  row id 4

```
4       7156       2020-10-26      test           0          14        1
```

I was trying the query below, but dont get good result.

```
 select s.id, t.* 
    from [articles ] s
    join (
        select Article, Date, Document, Out, count(*) as qty
        from [articles]
        group by Article, Date, Document, Out
        having count(*) > 1
    ) t on s.Article= t.Article and s.Date= t.Date and s.Document= t.Document and s.Out = t.out
```

Is this possible to find directly through query in MYSQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select *
from articles
where (article, document, in) in (
  select article, document, in 
  from articles 
  group by article, document, in
  habing count(*) > 1
)
```

This will return both duplicate rows:

```
id  |  Article    | Date        |  Document   |   In    |   Out   |   Status
1       7156       2020-10-26      test           0          14        1
4       7156       2020-10-26      test           0          14        1
```

Alternatively, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to select the second, third, etc. duplicates of a row based in its `id`. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by article, document, in order by id) as rn
  from articles
) x
where rn > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `exists` for this:

```
select a.*
from articles a
where exists (
    select 1
    from articles a1
    wehre 
        a1.article      = a.article 
        and a1.document = a.document
        and a1.in       = a.in
        and a1.id       < a.id
)
```